# how to unlock my radio alpine ine-w925r in BMW

Tags: audio, bmw

I just bought a 1998 BMW 323i, which came with an alpine ine-w925r radio
with serial number: S21011190A
The problem is that it is blocked, and the owner of the car, who had not moved it for more than 3 years, does not remember the code, is there any way to unlock or reset the radio?

I leave you a link where they do a review of the radio so you know what it is, thanks.

Link: http://www.accesoriosparacoches.com/radios-multimedia-alpine/58-alpine-ine-w925r-4958043541591.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I managed to solve it in the simplest way, after investigating the history of my car I managed to find the first owner, who unfortunately had passed away, but I was able to contact his children and they were able to provide me with the unlock code